# How to check the progress of Alter command in Amazon RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, alter, processlist

Is there any way to check the progress of Alter command in Amazon RDS Mysql service ?

We can see the query running / killed / stopped in the processlist easily but is there any way to find the data completed / percentage of Alter operation completed ?

Thanks

Comment: I found a post regarding this: https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/02/26/monitor-alter-table-progress-innodb_file_per_table/

Comment: @Stony this is totally different thing.